# Why would the type byte[] waste 31 bytes of space for each element?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, storage, bytes

The [Solidity Docs (v0.8.4)](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/types.html) states:

> The type byte[] is an array of bytes, but due to padding rules, it wastes 31 bytes of space for each element (except in storage). It is better to use the bytes type instead.

I couldn't find much info about this online. I've 3 questions:

1. What are the padding rules in this case?
2. What is considered as an 'element'?
3. Is there an example of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The smallest addressable chunk of storage is a 32-byte word. Arrays lay out the elements in separate words in discrete locations, so each single-byte element will be in its own slot.

The smallest read/write op handles a full word even if many variables are packed in.

The compiler will pack them in if they "fit". This `struct` can read two variables in one SREAD:

```
struct TwentyOne {
  address a;
  bool b;
}

TwentyOne[] ;
```

"Array of bytes" has one word to store the length of the array, and one word *for each element in the array*. This is because it needs to be able to "jump" to a row. Consider that the memory is organized approximately like:

- Length => EVM "slot": 3 (uint256 word)
- row1 => EVM "slot": 1 byte, 31 wasted
- row2 => EVM "slot": 1 byte, 31 wasted
- row3 => EVM "slot": 1 byte, 31 wasted

A "slot" is always a 32-byte word and is the smallest unit of state storage that can be accessed.

Hope it helps.

Comment: so would: string a = "abcdefg" - create a 32-byte word for each character? In this case string a would consume 7 chunks of storage at 32 bytes each?

Comment: @RobHitchens suppose i want to save the value 0xabcdef in a dynamic bytes array (not in bytes3), In this case also will it require one slot to store the data ? Also is another memory slot required to store the length value in case of dynamic byte array ?

Comment: It will take four "words" so the elements can be accessed by row.